# Diffrence among environment/profile/bash files

Tags: bash, .profile, environment

I know the difference among `~/.bash`, `~/.profile` vs. `/etc/profile`. I know (please correct me if I am wrong) configuration in `~/.bash` is applicable for a specific user and terminal only.Configuration in `~/.profile` applicable for a user only.

But sometimes I found some configuration like environment variable are also set in `/etc/environment` file. **What are the difference among these file?**

I also found that in `/etc/environment` file we do not export environment variable while we export environment variable (like PATH) from `~/.bash` and `~/.profile` -

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java #for ~/.bash or ~/.profile  
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java #for /etc/environment
```

**Why these difference among the two type of ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/environment` isn't used by Bash but by read by [pam-env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_env.8.html) at login time.

That's why `/etc/environment` doesn't allow any shell syntax but only simple

```
NAME=value
```

lines.